# Longest common contiguous subsequence - algorithm

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, sequences

My question is simple: Is there an O(n) algorithm for finding the longest contiguous subsequence between two sequences A and B? I searched it, but all the results were about the LCS problem, which is not what I'm seeking.

*Note:* if you are willing to give any sample code, you are more than welcome to do so, but please, if you can, in C or C++.

*Edit:* Here is an example:

```
A: { a, b, a, b, b, b, a }
B: { a, d, b, b, b, c, n }
longest common contiguous subsequence: { b, b, b }
```

Comment: If you aren't seeking lcs please supply a trivial example of what you are seeking

Comment: This is the same as the longest common substring.

Comment: that looks the same as LCS. Or is it LCS with the additional constraint that the sequence must be a repetition of the same symbols?  i.e. `{a,b,c,d,d}` and `{d,d,a,b,c}` yields `{d,d}`?

Comment: Clarifying fgb's comment for other newbs like me: Longest Common Contiguous Subsequence = Longest Common String. As Wikipedia says, " unlike substrings, subsequences are not required to occupy consecutive positions within the original sequences". Hence "contiguous subsequence" or "consecutive subsequence" can be replaced by "substring".

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can do this in linear time.  One way is by building suffix trees for both the pattern and the text and computing their intersection.  I can't think of a way to do this without involving suffix trees or suffix arrays, though.

Comment: The solution with suffix trees is not linear.

Comment: @RondogiannisAristophanes [yes, it is](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_substring_problem#Suffix_tree). It's linear in n + m, so it's linear in n if n = m.

Comment: It takes linear time to build a suffix tree.  (Surprising, but true.)  Suffix trees take linear space.  Walking two suffix trees simultaneously to find the longest common string takes linear time.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure whether there exists an O(n) algorithm. Here is a O(n*n) dynamic solution, maybe it is helpful to you. Let lcs_con[i][j] represent the longest common contiguous subsequence which end with element A_i from array A and B_j from array B. Then we can get the equations below:

```
lcs_con[i][j]=0 if i==0 or j==0
lcs_con[i][j]=0 if A_i != B_j
lcs_con[i][j]=lcs_con[i-1][j-1] if A_i==B_j
```

we can record the maximum of lcs_con[i][j] and the ending index during the calculation to get the longest common contiguous subsequence. The code is below:

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;


int main()
{
    char A[7]={'a','b','a','b','b','b','a'};
    char B[7]={'a','d','b','b','b','c','n'};

    int lcs_con[8][8];    
    memset(lcs_con,0,8*8*sizeof(int));

    int result=-1;
    int x=-1;
    int y=-1;

    for(int i=1;i<=7;++i)
      for(int j=1;j<=7;++j)
      {
          if(A[i-1]==B[j-1])lcs_con[i][j]=lcs_con[i-1][j-1]+1;
          else lcs_con[i][j]=0;

          if(lcs_con[i][j]>result)
          {
               result=lcs_con[i][j];
               x=i;
               y=j;                   
          }
      }

   if(result==-1)cout<<"There are no common contiguous subsequence";
   else
   {
       cout<<"The longest common contiguous subsequence is:"<<endl;
       for(int i=x-result;i<x;i++)cout<<A[i];
       cout<<endl;
   }

   getchar();
   getchar();

   return 0;    
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: I think there is a typo: `lcs_con[i][j]=lcs_con[i-1][j-1] if A_i==B_j` should be `lcs_con[i][j]=lcs_con[i-1][j-1] + 1 if A_i==B_j`

Answer (score 0):

that is what you are looking for:

[KMP algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm) `c` [implementation](http://barnyard.syr.edu/quickies/kmp.c)

the basic theory:

1. [How to find Longest Common Substring using C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10248728/longest-common-substring)
2. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_substring_problem

Comment: This sounds interesting. Could you please briefly explain this algorithm?

Comment: Didn't you understand the wiki summary? in corman algo book there is a nice explanation as well

Comment: KMP would not be linear, since you need to run it more than one time. You need a suffix tree.

Comment: The fastest solution I can think of that uses KMP will be quadratic.  Can you elaborate?