# Return the longest common Substring Function c ++

Tags: c++, substring, c-strings

```
string longest_common_Substring(string a, string b) {

string best = ""; 
string subString = ""; 
//vector < vector<int>> s[a.length]; 

int max = a.length() + b.length(); 


for (int i = 0; i <= a.length(); i++)
{
    for (int k = 0; k <= b.length() -i - 1; k++)
    {
        subString = a.substr(i, k);
        if (b.find(subString)== true && subString.length() > best.length())
        {
            best = subString;
        }
    }

}

return best; }
```

My sample input is  longest_common_Substring("the rain", " in spain") and the output is "in". The correct output is "ain"

Comment: After almost five years as a member, it's really time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also [take the SO tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). And of course learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I also recommend that you read [this SO question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/), and all of http://idownvotedbecau.se/ to learn some reasons why you will get negative votes on your question in its current state.

Comment: Lastly, please search for "longest common substring c++". It will give you a lot of hits, including many here on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find Longest Common Substring using C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10248728/how-to-find-longest-common-substring-using-c)

Comment: @FantasticMrFox In this case OP needs to debug and fix their code. I don't think "just remove it and copy another implementation" is an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change your `if` condition. `string::find` returns the position of the found string or `string::npos` if no string was found. `string::find` does not work with `true` and `false`. `true` is converted to `1`. Therefor `b.find(subString)== true` is only true if `subString` is found at position 1 in `b`. You can verify this behavior with

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::string a = "Text";

    if (a.find("Text") == true) std::cout << 1 << std::endl;
    if (a.find("ext") == true) std::cout << 2 << std::endl;
    if (a.find("xt") == true) std::cout << 3 << std::endl;
    if (a.find("t") == true) std::cout << 4 << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Output is `2`

Try

```
b.find(subString) != b.npos
```

to fix your problem.

Comment: I added a code to verify my statement. If my explanation is wrong, please correct me.

Comment: `Only 1 is converted to true` - Correction, anything except 0 is true.

Comment: Why is the result of my code example `2`? And not also `3` and `4`? Why is the result of the code in the question `in` and not `ain`?

Comment: Because you have it backwards. In this specific conversion, true is converted into 1.

Comment: Thanks, that explains it.

Comment: Thank you this fixed my issue.