# Optimal Substructure Property

Tags: algorithm, lcs

suppose we have two Strings X,Y of length n,m respectively.
I found the longest common subsequence Z of X and Y.

how can I prove the optimal substructure property of the longest common subsequence (LCS) ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find Longest Common Substring using C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10248728/how-to-find-longest-common-substring-using-c)

Answer (score 1):

To prove for optimality in the substructures of the problem, you need to first start with defining what your `state` is.

LCS problem:

```
Strings: X, Y
X = x1x2.....xN #length=N
Y = y1y2.....yM #length=M
```

### Define States

For LCS problem, lets define our state `D[i,j]` as:

```
D[i,j] = longest common subsequence of substrings X[1:i] and Y[1:j]

Based on our definition above, we are looking to find the value of **D[N, M]**
```

### Come up with recurrence-relation (D[i,j]):

#### Case 1:

```
x[i] == y[j] 

1. If the characters we are comparing are already the same, it can very well be part of the longest-common-subsequence for X[1:i] and Y[1:j].
2. The LCS might also turn-out from X[1:i-1] & Y[1:j]; OR
3. turn-out from X[1:i] & Y[1:j-1]

Thus,
D[i][j] = maxlen(D[i-1][j-1] + {X[i]}, D[i-1][j], D[i][j-1])
```

#### Case 2:

```
x[i] != y[j]

Argument follows directly from previous case:

D[i][j] = maxlen(D[i-1][j], D[i][j-1])
```

The reasoning for optimality follows from **Induction** since we build the final-answer `D[N,M]` from bottom-to-top.